# Facebook Recent Logins breaks OAuth flow

Tags: facebook, oauth

I'm having troubles working with what appears to be an error with Facebook's OAuth server-side flow. When logging into Facebook using `"Recent Logins"`, Facebook does not redirect back to my calling application. Instead it goes directly to the Facebook home page.

If I login to Facebook using the email/password fields at the top right of the screen, then the redirection becomes successful.

Is there some way to force facebook to send users to [it's main login page](https://www.facebook.com/login) and not [this main page](https://www.facebook.com/) that displays the recent logins  when they are not already logged into Facebook?

This also occurs using Facebook's very own OAuth for [developers](https://developers.facebook.com). So I know it can't be just me.

1. Login to Facebook.com
2. Logout
3. Visit [facebook's apps page](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)
4. Click your profile pic and enter your password (rather than using the blue banner to login).
5. Facebook redirects you to their home page rather than [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)

What would be great is a parameter to [this page](https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/dialog/oauth) that would allow me to force a particular facebook login dialog as a workaround.

Comment: Looks like a ticket has been opened with Facebook. https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1079085552292507/